# How to add default options

Tags: laravel-5

I just want to add default 'Please select' with selectMonth(), selectRange() and selectYear() function

my code

```
<div class="col-md-1"> {!! Form::selectRange('day', 1, 31) !!}</div>
<div class="col-md-1"> {!! Form::selectMonth('month') !!}</div>
<div class="col-md-1">{!! Form::selectYear('year', 1950, 2015) !!}</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way.
Just do by yourself.

```
Form::select('day', ['' => 'Select day'] + array_combine(range(1, 31), range(1, 31)))
Form::select('month', array_merge(['' => 'Select month'], range(1, 12)))
Form::select('year', ['' => 'Select year'] + array_combine(range(1950, 2015), range(1950, 2015)))
```

But I think that's ugly. Why don't you use any datepicker plugin?https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Update:

```
$months = array(); 
foreach (range(1, 12) as $month) { 
    $months[$month] = strftime($format, mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1)); 
}

Form::select('month', array_merge(['' => 'Select month'], $months))
```

Comment: work for day and year but stuck in month select because it show only numbers

Comment: date field in three select one for day one foe month and one for year so how i use the date picker

Comment: To display month by Text, you need to convert from number to text.

$months = array();

  foreach (range(1, 12) as $month)
  {
   $months[$month] = strftime($format, mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1));
  }

End pass $month to view, or create new Form::macro to do it easier

Comment: i m doing lik this {!! Form::select('month', array('' => 'Select month', 
    '1' => 'January', '2' => 'February', '3' => 'March', '4' => 'April', '5' => 'May', '6' => 'June', '7' => 'July', '8' => 'August', '9' => 'September', '10' => 'October', '11' => 'November', '12' => 'December')) !!}

Comment: one more thing for year it take value of years 1,2,3 which is quit difficut to handle in edit when i want to show selected

Comment: I add new solution. But they become so ugly. I think you need create some Macro to pretifier code. Check out this link http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/173/creating-form-macros

Comment: @ Lê Trần Tiến Trung thanks for help i use a datepicker. but for help thanku very much but your answere also work :)